# Change DIV CSS class with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to change the CSS class based on radio buttons and it does work, however it will only run once. E.g. If I select the white radio button then select oak, selecting white does nothing until a page refresh. I'm most certainly doing something wrong and any help would be appreciated.

```js
$("#radio").on('change','input[type=radio]', (function() { 
  if($("#oakradio").is(":checked")) {
    $("#over").removeAttr();
    $('#over').addClass('oak');
  }
  else if($("#whiteradio").is(":checked")) {
    $("#over").removeAttr();
    $('#over').addClass('white');
  }
  else if($("#mocharadio").is(":checked")) {
    $("#over").removeAttr();
    $('#over').addClass('mocha');
  }
}));
```

```css
    #over.mocha {
      background-image: url("https://photography.bytebros.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/09/pan_mocha.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 515px;
      width: 1190px;
      margin: 0 auto 30px;
      position: relative;
    }

    iframe {
      height: 333px;
      width: 1000px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 93px;
      left: 93px;
    }

    #over.white {
      background-image: url("https://photography.bytebros.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/09/pan_white.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 515px;
      width: 1190px;
      margin: 0 auto 30px;
      position: relative;
    }

    #over.oak {
      background-image: url("https://photography.bytebros.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/09/pan_oak.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 515px;
      width: 1190px;
      margin: 0 auto 30px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="over" class="mocha">
  <iframe src="http://photography.bytebros.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2017/09/photo71000333.png"></iframe>
</div>
<form id="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="white" id="whiteradio">White<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="oak" id="oakradio">Oak<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="mocha" id="mocharadio">Mocha<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `removeClass` and `addClass`. Don't use `removeAttr()`.

Also, you can simplify your code to 2 lines only.

```
$("#radio").on('change','input[type=radio]',(function() { 
  var color = $(this).val();
  $('#over').removeClass("white mocha oak").addClass(color);
}));
```

Comment: This is a superior answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are not removing the previous class you are just adding them.
Change your `.removeAttr()` with `.removeClass()`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8f2bru0k/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `removeClass()` method instead to reset your classes. `removeAttr()` is used to remove specific attributes such as onclick handlers or titles as specified in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

By using `removeClass()` you effectively reset the classes on `#over`. Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yzg7j8xz/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might be using `.removeAttr` since `.removeClass` is a bit buggy in a few versions of jQuery.

Instead of removing the class attribute, just set class attribute using `.attr()`instead:

```
$("#radio").on('change','input[type=radio]',(function() { 
  if($("#oakradio").is(":checked")){
    $("#over").attr("class", "oak");
  }
  else if($("#whiteradio").is(":checked")){
     $("#over").attr("class", "white");
  }
  else if($("#mocharadio").is(":checked")){
    $("#over").attr("class", "mocha");
  }
}));
```